# Not a valid Odata path template

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

I am trying to create Odata method that satisfy url like

> domain:port/products/100/RedirectUrl()

```
[ODataRoute("{id}/RedirectUrl()")]
public IHttpActionResult RedirectUrl(int id)
{
   return Redirect("myUrl" + id);
}
```

but i got exception like

> The path template '{id}/RedirectUrl()' on the action 'RedirectUrl' in
>   controller 'Products' is not a valid OData path template

My Webapi config contains

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
builder.EntityType<Product>().Function("RedirectUrl").Returns<IHttpActionResult>();
```

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to enable Key as segment, track this https://github.com/OData/WebApi/pulls, then you can set the UrlConventions.ODataUrlConventions to enable it. Or you have to override the [DefaultODataPathHandler](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Routing/DefaultODataPathHandler.cs) to achieve this, may need to copy some private method like Parse.